# Combining pyramid with cornice and basic auth does password checking twice, how to prevent?

Tags: security, pyramid, basic-authentication, cornice

Currently I am working on a project that combines basic authentication with the cornice / pyramid framework.

From the logging I observe that every time a url is access the used credentials get checked twice. Since in our user case this does involve a lot of database checks, it is a potential target for an (unintended) DoS attack.

In my view I define a cornice Service with a factory.
In my app setup I configured the pyramid provided BasicAuthenticationPolicy with the resource intensive check as a callback for authentication
Also in the app setup I configure the pyramid provided ACLAuthorizationPolicy for authorisation.

So I was wondering, what I am missing, as I would really like to prevent the second check to take place. (Should I cache this on the request object in some secure way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found by studing the code this is intended behaviour.

This behaviour is only triggered when the authenticated_userid property is used (which I do).

Solved this issue by 'caching' call's to my authentication function via a decorator. Which should be fine as the same objects will be referenced via the function parameters.

Documentation can be found in the pyramid package `pyramid/authentication.py`